# Send HTML E-Mail by Web Service

Tags: c#, html, web, service

I need to send an E-Mail with a HTML message with Web Service but i don't know how to do it, I'm new at c#

I tried to do this way but it says the name message does not exist in the current context

```
    try
    {
        message.To.Add("rafaelcassino@live.com");
        message.To.Remove(new MailAddress(destinatario));
        message.Subject = assunto;
        message.From = new MailAddress("wsafer@sirsan.com.br");
        message.IsBodyHtml = false;

        message.Body = “olá mensagem de teste \n  “  + assunto;

        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.sirsan.com.br");

        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
        smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("wsafer@sirsan.com.br", "abcd@123");

        smtp.Port = 587;

        smtp.Send(message);

        return "mensagem enviada com sucesso";
    }
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        return "erro ao mandar o E-Mail" + ex.Message;
    }
```

Comment: Where do you declare your `message`?

Comment: As the error is trying to tell you, you need to declare your variable.

Comment: Also `message.IsBodyHtml = false;` seems unlikely to be what you want given the title ...

Answer (score 3):

Declare the "message" variable before using it like this

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage()
```